Extending $\mathbb{R}$ to a higher dimensional manifold
If a topological space $X$ is Hausdorff, connected, second countable, homogeneous (i.e. it has transitive homeomorphism group) and embeds the real line $\mathbb{R}$, does it follow that $X$ is a topological manifold of finite or infinite dimension?

Shall we assume that "embeds the real line" means: "contains a subspace that is homeomorphic to ℝ ?  If so, another example is the compact topological group known as the solenoid. (I am thinking of what is called the dyadic solenoid, but there are also many others.)

Already answered (twice) but let me add the comment that one can easily construct an example by taking a product of the real line with a space which has the desired properties but is not a manifold.

(so long as one can ensure that $\Bbb R \times X$ remains non-manifold, e.g. if the local homology is wrong at some point).

If by ‘manifold’ you mean locally Euclidean then the answer is no. The power $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ of the real line, the Hilbert cube, every $\ell_p$-space, …, there are very many infinite-dimensional, connected, second-countable, and homogeneous spaces that contain a topological copy of the real line.

Thank you. My intention was to include the possibility of infinite dimension. I have edited the question accordingly.

The existing answer already settles the question as stated, but let me add that the answer is negative even among finite dimensional spaces, the Menger curve is a one-dimensional and homogeneous Peano continuum, which contains many copies of $\Bbb R$ (it is arcwise connected), but is not a manifold.

Thank you, this is a very interesting counterexample.  I have accepted @rediscoveringamerica answer because of generality.
